# "Automatic brace completion" keeps reverting to selected

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have problem with **Visual Studio Community 2015**. When I uncheck the ***Tools|Text Editor|All Languages|Automatic brace completion*** option, it always reverts back to selected. Anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Same problem bro, here is [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279735/automation-brace-completion-for-python-doesnt-work)

Comment: I think that the setting is actually saved. If you look at each language option in turn, "Automatic brace completion" is turned off.

Comment: I have the same problem. Has anyone found the solution? I'm running Visual Studio 2015 as Administrator, so it should have the elevated privilege to save whatever settings it needs to save...