# Visual Studio: python brace, bracket, and quotation mark completion

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I started using visual studio for python but one thing that is really annoying is that visual studio does not support brace, bracket, and quotation mark completion for python.  It does for c++, c#, and almost all the other languages it supports but it doesn't for python. In the options t has a check box for brace completion but it is grayed out and doesn't work.  Is there anyway to enable this or are there any extensions for doing this on Visual Studio 2015?  I would appreciate any answers or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this post on GitHub, the feature is currently still in the backlog and not completed at this point:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1484.

To quote *mhegazy* on June 2, 2015:

"This is still on our backlog at the moment."

Comment: Apparently, it turns out that this applies to TypeScript, not Python. However, I would assume the same reasoning applies to why it is not yet available for Python at this point.

Comment: Is there a way around it?  I found a brace completion extension for an older version of Visual Studio but nothing for 2015.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it! Looking at this page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526847/automatic-brace-completion-keeps-reverting-to-selected) it seems that the feature simply doesn't exist for several languages yet and is still in the works.

Comment: That is to bad it seems like something they would spend time developing since almost every other IDE I know of has that functionality.  Oh well.

Comment: If you can, check out PyCharm - I highly recommend it.